# Unable to run Gradle app engine tasks

Tags: java, gradle, google-cloud-platform

I'm really confused about converting an old Google App Engine project to Gradle.

I'm trying to follow the instructions on [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle) page. It advises to start with this build script:

```
buildscript {    // Configuration for building
  repositories {
    jcenter()    // Bintray's repository - a fast Maven Central mirror & more
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'    // latest App Engine Gradle tasks
  }
}

repositories {   // repositories for Jar's you access in your code
  maven {
    url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'             // Google's mirror of Maven Central
//   url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' // SNAPSHOT Repository (if needed)
  }
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'                              // standard Java tasks
apply plugin: 'war'                               // standard Web Archive plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'  // App Engine tasks

dependencies {
  providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'2.5'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'
// Add your dependencies here.

}

appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
  run {      // local (dev_appserver) configuration (standard environments only)
    port = 8080                 // default
  }

  deploy {   // deploy configuration
    stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
    promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
  }
}

group = 'com.example.appengine'   // Generated output GroupId
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'          // Version in generated output

sourceCompatibility = 1.7  // App Engine Standard uses Java 7
targetCompatibility = 1.7  // App Engine Standard uses Java 7
```

However it doesn't work:

```
$ gradle appengineRun

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/path/to/myproject/build.gradle' line: 32

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myproject'.
> Could not find method run() for arguments [build_c1i62diotjttavcmtjg1zqlbd$_run_closure3$_closure5@33f17289] on root project 'myproject' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Shouldn't the dependencies be downloaded to make the custom `appengine` task configuration work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please have a look at the [sources](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/gradle/appengine/AppEnginePlugin.java) of the plugin. When the core plugin is applied it decides whether to apply a *flexible* or *standard* appengine plugin. Since there's probably no `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml` flexible plugin is applied which does not create the extension that fails (FYI, this extension is created [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/gradle/appengine/standard/AppEngineStandardPlugin.java#L76)). To fix the problem run:

```
mkdir -p src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
```

and then:

```
touch src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
```

in console where `build.gradle` is located. This will solve the problem. Poor documentation :/

Comment: Hah, I was wondering about the `appengine-web.xml` file - it is mentioned on the original page, but no content is suggested for it. btw maybe `mkdir` instead of `md`? Thanks though, this worked.

Comment: @DanGravell, as I said poor docs' quality. Corrected to `mkdir`, thanks.